# Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing in maven with GAE and Spring Roo

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, gwt, spring-roo

I'm using Spring roo with Google App Engine So, I'm using maven GWT plugin  to compile my code like this inside my pom.xml :

```
<extraJvmArgs>-javaagent:"${gae.home}/lib/agent/appengine-agent.jar"
                    -Xmx1024m</extraJvmArgs>
```

where in pom.xml, `gae.home` is (`gae.version` is `1.8.3`)

```
<gae.home>${user.home}\.m2\repository\com\google\appengine\appengine-java-sdk\${gae.version}\appengine-java-sdk\appengine-java-sdk-${gae.version}</gae.home>
```

Yet, I get the error when I run `-DskipTests appengine:devserver`

> [ERROR] Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\com\google\appengine\appengine-java-sdk\1.8.3\appengine-java-sdk\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.3/lib/agent/appengine-agent.jar
>   [ERROR] -Xmx1024m
>   [INFO] agent library failed to init: instrument
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] Total time: 12.419 s
>   [INFO] Finished at: 2015-04-26T16:03:22+00:00
>   [INFO] Final Memory: 23M/225M
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.7.0:compile (gwtcompile) on project dp-demo-3: Command [[
>   [ERROR] C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\bin\java -javaagent:C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\com\google\appengine\appengine-java-sdk\1.8.3\appengine-java-sdk\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.3/lib/agent/appengine-agent.jar
>   [ERROR] -Xmx1024m -classpath C:\Users\bsmtaa\Documents\workspace-sts-3.6.4.RELEASE\dp-demo-3\target\dp-demo-3-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\classes;C:\Users\bsmtaa\Documents\workspace-sts-3.6.4.RELEASE\dp-demo-3\src\main\java;C:\Users\bsmtaa\Documents\workspace-sts-3.6.4.RELEASE\dp-demo-3\src\main\aspect;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.17\log4j-1.2.17.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.5\slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\1.7.5\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.5.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-log4j12\1.7.5\slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjrt\1.7.4\aspectjrt-1.7.4.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.7.4\aspectjweaver-1.7.4.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\javax\servlet\servlet-api\2.5\servlet-api-2.5.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\net\sf\flexjson\flexjson\2.1\flexjson-2.1.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.1\commons-lang3-3.1.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\org\springframework\roo\org.springframework.roo.annotations\1.2.5.RELEASE\org.springframework.roo.annotations-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\3.2.6.RELEASE\spring-core-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\3.2.6.RELEASE\spring-context-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\3.2.6.RELEASE\spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\3.2.6.RELEASE\spring-expression-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\3.2.6.RELEASE\spring-aop-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\3.2.6.RELEASE\spring-aspects-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context-support\3.2.6.RELEASE\spring-context-support-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\com\google\appengine\orm\datanucleus-appengine\2.1.1\datanucleus-appengine-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\org\datanucleus\datanucleus-enhancer\3.1.1\datanucleus-enhancer-3.1.1.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\org\ow2\asm\asm\4.0\asm-4.0.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\com\google\appengine\appengine-api-1.0-sdk\1.8.3\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.8.3.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec\1.1\geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec-1.1.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\org\datanucleus\datanucleus-core\3.1.3\datanucleus-core-3.1.3.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\org\datanucleus\datanucleus-rdbms\3.1.3\datanucleus-rdbms-3.1.3.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\org\datanucleus\datanucleus-api-jpa\3.1.3\datanucleus-api-jpa-3.1.3.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\org\datanucleus\datanucleus-api-jdo\3.1.3\datanucleus-api-jdo-3.1.3.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\javax\jdo\jdo-api\3.0\jdo-api-3.0.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\javax\transaction\transaction-api\1.1\transaction-api-1.1.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-validator\4.3.1.Final\hibernate-validator-4.3.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.1.0.CR2\jboss-logging-3.1.0.CR2.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.0.0.GA\validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\javax\transaction\jta\1.1\jta-1.1.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\3.2.6.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\3.2.6.RELEASE\spring-tx-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\3.2.6.RELEASE\spring-orm-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\commons-pool\commons-pool\1.5.6\commons-pool-1.5.6.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\commons-dbcp\commons-dbcp\1.4\commons-dbcp-1.4.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\3.2.6.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\3.2.6.RELEASE\spring-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\org\springframework\webflow\spring-js-resources\2.2.1.RELEASE\spring-js-resources-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\commons-digester\commons-digester\2.1\commons-digester-2.1.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils\1.8.3\commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\commons-fileupload\commons-fileupload\1.2.2\commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\javax\servlet\jsp\jstl\jstl-api\1.2\jstl-api-1.2.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\org\glassfish\web\jstl-impl\1.2\jstl-impl-1.2.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\javax\el\el-api\2.2\el-api-2.2.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\joda-time\joda-time\1.6\joda-time-1.6.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\javax\servlet\jsp\jsp-api\2.1\jsp-api-2.1.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.5\commons-codec-1.5.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\org\apache\tiles\tiles-jsp\2.2.2\tiles-jsp-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\org\apache\tiles\tiles-servlet\2.2.2\tiles-servlet-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\org\apache\tiles\tiles-core\2.2.2\tiles-core-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\org\apache\tiles\tiles-template\2.2.2\tiles-template-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\org\apache\tiles\tiles-api\2.2.2\tiles-api-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-servlet\2.7.0\gwt-servlet-2.7.0.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-user\2.7.0\gwt-user-2.7.0.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\org\json\json\20090211\json-20090211.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\inject\gin\1.5.0\gin-1.5.0.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\com\google\inject\guice\3.0-rc2\guice-3.0-rc2.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\javax\inject\javax.inject\1\javax.inject-1.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\com\google\inject\extensions\guice-assistedinject\3.0-rc2\guice-assistedinject-3.0-rc2.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.0.0.GA\validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\xalan\xalan\2.7.1\xalan-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\xalan\serializer\2.7.1\serializer-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\xml-apis\xml-apis\1.3.04\xml-apis-1.3.04.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-user\2.7.0\gwt-user-2.7.0.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.0.0.GA\validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.0.0.GA\validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-dev\2.7.0\gwt-dev-2.7.0.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\org\ow2\asm\asm\5.0.3\asm-5.0.3.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\org\ow2\asm\asm-util\5.0.3\asm-util-5.0.3.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\org\ow2\asm\asm-tree\5.0.3\asm-tree-5.0.3.jar;C:\Users\bsmtaa.m2\repository\org\ow2\asm\asm-commons\5.0.3\asm-commons-5.0.3.jar com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler -logLevel INFO -style PRETTY -war C:\Users\bsmtaa\Documents\workspace-sts-3.6.4.RELEASE\dp-demo-3\target\dp-demo-3-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT -localWorkers 4 -XfragmentCount -1 -sourceLevel auto -gen C:\Users\bsmtaa\Documents\workspace-sts-3.6.4.RELEASE\dp-demo-3\target.generated com.mta.ifekry.dp.backend.ApplicationScaffold
>   [ERROR] ]] failed with status 1

Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting all the repositories you have downloaded and right click on the project and configure it to "clean compile". Then the folder will be automatically downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I got similar error
The problem was in incorrect path, usage '/' instead of '\'
Here I can see similar issue
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5wjq.png)